# Flag field conversion from old table to new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm kinda new to SQL Server (currently working on 2012 version). My question is the following.

I'm restructuring an old database schema where `true`/`false` flags are maintained in `varchar(1)` fields *(i.e. 'Y' -> true, 'N' -> false)*. I'm currently doing a deep restructuring and for these reason each old schema table is replaced by a new one. In this scenario flags are now stored in `bit` fields and I need a script that copies all the values contained in a old table, performs the flag conversion (where needed) and inserts them in the new table.

What is the best and fast way to do this?

My idea is:

- Select only `'Y'` valued records and insert them in the new table with the bit fields as `1`
- Select only `'N'` valued records and insert them in the new table with the bit fields as `0`

I'm sure that T-SQL offers a more powerful way to accomplish this conversion. Thanks for every suggestion.

Comment: google "SQL CASE Statement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO` new table using Select from old table using `Case` Statement

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (flagNewTableCol,othercolumns)
SELECT CASE WHEN flagColunn = 'Y' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END, othercolumns
FROM OldTable
```

Comment: I think that really needs an else since the original table could be storing something besides a 'y' or  'n'

Comment: @Ghost:- Agreed, modified

Answer (score 2):

How about using a `case` statement?

```
insert into newtable(flagcol, . . .)
    select (case when oldflag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end), . . .
    from oldtable;
```